# How to SUM if date falls in a particular month and is a positive value

Tags: excel-formula

`=SUM(IF(MONTH($M$3:$M$41982)=1,$K$3:$K$41982,">0"))`

How to SUM positive values falling in a particular month? 
I am entering this but not getting an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($M$3:$M$41982)=1)*($K$3:$K$41982>0)*$K$3:$K$41982)
```

---

You weren't far off with your original formula. You just need to split out evaluating if `$K$3:$K$41982` is greater than `0` and then returning the value of `$K$3:$K$41982`

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH(A1:A8)=1,IF(B1:B8>0,B1:B8,0)))
```

With this formula, you have to enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>